# Using HttpClient to POST to Form but Getting SSLPeerUnverifiedException yet browser Works Fine

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

Using HttpClient 4.1.0, we're trying to connect to a remote server that normally would be connected to using a form. By the way, this will be for production use but I would not call the information we're sending sensitive. I'm not sure if they will insist on an https connection anyway.

When we try to call  httpClient.execute(httpPost), it throws a SSLPeerUnverifiedException

We're creating a DefaultHttpClient using a ThreadSafeClientConnManager and have verified that the https registry is associated with a SSLSocketFactory.

We're connecting to a url like this: https://some.thingchangedtoprotectthem.com/servlet/servlet.Something

Why would the browser work like a charm, but using a server side process blows up with that exception? Is it because the browser comes with verisign certificates and HttpClient does not?

```
System.out and Stack trace below:
    schemeSocketFactory = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
    javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
          at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:345)
          at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
          at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:390)
          at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
          at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
          at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
          at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:562)
          at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
          at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
          at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
          at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
```

Comment: After thinking about this more, there may be one or two items they want secure but I will check on that. I may change my strategy entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed.  You should to have a look at this [blog post](http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/) where the author describes how to download and install a certificate in your keystore.  It's written as an article for Android developers, but it most definitely applies to your case.

Worst case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https) will tell you how to trust all certificates, though that's not a very good idea. ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Is it because the browser comes with verisign certificates and HttpClient does not?"

Almost certainly.

See [this message](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-httpclient-users/200903.mbox/%3C22728600.post@talk.nabble.com%3E) for ideas on how to fix it.